# No feature for name ['/appointments'] exception elasticsearch on heroku using Tire gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, heroku, tire

I am using Tire gem in rails application for elasticsearch and for heroku i am using seachbox add-on.Things are working perfectly in my local machine but on heroku it gives an error while creating and index which is

> [ERROR] There has been an error when creating the index --
>   elasticsearch returned:500 :
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"exception","reason":"No feature for
>   name [/appointments]"}],"type":"exception","reason":"No feature for
>   name [/appointments]"},"status":500}

My `production.rb` contains the url configuration which tire needs

```
Tire.configure do
   url ENV['SEARCHBOX_URL']
end
```

Does this need any further configurations for index creating as when i run even `rails console` on heroku it gives me same error every time.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: No i haven't got any solution for this yet